# Who was the last Indian player to beat Vishy, and when?

Tags: history, famous-players, anand

The question came to mind following today's game between Vishy (Viswanathan Anand) and the young Raunak Sadhwani at the Isle of Man 2018 Tournament. Has Vishy been beaten by an Indian player since, say, the mid-90s?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is: Yes

```
Krishnan Sasikiran vs Viswanathan Anand
FIDE World Cup-C (2002), Hyderabad, rd 2, Oct-05
King's Indian Attack: Yugoslav Variation (A07)
1-0
```

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1357060

Comment: Thank you very much for the research! It must still be some sort of record, given Vishy's unique stature in Indian chess. Top Russian players are beaten by other Russians all the time, given the depth of chess talent there. Even Carlsen was beaten by Hammer in Norway not long ago.

Answer (score 4):

Given this question was asked a while ago, the answer has obviously changed.
[Pentala Harikrishna won a classical game against Anand in the 37th European Chess Club Cup 2022](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2387105), held on October 2022. Apart from that, [Vidit Santosh Gujrathi won a blitz game in 2019 at the Grand Chess Tour Tata Steel Chess Indian Blitz](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/grand-chess-tour-tata-steel-india-2019/23/1/2).